# Error in v-on handler: "Error: Reference.set failed: First argument contains undefined"

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-realtime-database

Where could The blow error be occurring? I have been staring at this for awhile and cannot figure  it out. I have tried to console log, all of the data that is being imputed into the database and they all have values...

[image]

I am trying to push the current message to the database in order to create a real time chat app. Provided below is the code.

This project is using firebase and VueJs.

CreateMessage.vue (where I believe the error is)

```
<template>
    <div class="container" style="margin-bottom: 30px">
        <form>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter message ..." v-model="newMessage">
                <p class="text-danger" v-if="errorText">{{ errorText }}</p>
            </div>

            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"  @click.stop.prevent="createMessage"> Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import firebase from '../components/firebaseconfig';
    import AuthMonitor from '../AuthMonitor';
    import Login from '../components/Login';

    export default {
        name: 'CreateMessage',
        mixins:[AuthMonitor],
        data(){
            return {
                newMessage: "",
                errorText: "",
                user: firebase.auth().currentUser
            }
        },
        methods: {
            createMessage () {
                console.log(this.newMessage);
                if (this.newMessage != '') {
                    console.log(Date.now());
                    firebase.database().ref("messages").push().set({
                        message: this.newMessage,
                        name: this.user,
                        timestamp: Date.now()
                }).catch(err => {
                        console.log(err);
                    });
                this.newMessage = "";
                this.errorText = "";
                } else {
                    this.errorText = "A message must be entered!"
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

ChatRoom.vue . (the view)

```
<template>
    <div class="chat container" v-if="isAuth">
        <h2 class="text-primary text-center">Real-Time Chat</h2>
        <h5 class="text-secondary text-center">Powered by Vue.js & Firebase</h5>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <p class="nomessages text-secondary" v-if="messages.length == 0">
                    [No messages yet!]
                </p>
                <div class="messages" v-chat-scroll="{always: false, smooth: true}">
                    <div v-for="message in messages" :key="message.id">
                        <span class="text-info">[{{ message.name }}]: </span>
                        <span>{{message.message}}</span>
                        <span class="text-secondary time">{{message.timestamp}}</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-action">
                <CreateMessage/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import CreateMessage from '@/components/CreateMessage';
    import firebase from '../components/firebaseconfig';
    import AuthMonitor from '../AuthMonitor';
    import moment from 'moment';

    export default {
        name: 'Chat',
        mixins:[AuthMonitor],
        components: {
            CreateMessage
        },
        data() {
            return{
                messages: []
            }
        },
        // created() {
        //     let ref = firebase.database().ref('messages');

        //     ref.onSnapshot(snapshot => {
        //         snapshot.docChanges().forEach(change => {
        //             if (change.type == 'added') {
        //                 let doc = change.doc;
        //                 this.messages.push({
        //                     id: doc.id,
        //                     name: doc.data().name,
        //                     message: doc.data().message,
        //                     timestamp: moment(doc.data().timestamp).format('LTS')
        //                 });
        //             }
        //         });
        //     });
        // }
    }
</script>

<style>
.chat h2{
    font-size: 2.6em;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.chat h5{
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.chat span{
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

.chat .time{
    display: block;
    font-size: 0.7em;
}

.messages{
    max-height: 300px;
    overflow: auto;
}
</style>
```

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please don't show screenshots of text.  Copy the text into the question so it's easier to read, search, and copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is telling you that `this.user` contains a property `ja` which contains an undefined value.  You can't put undefined values into Realtime Database.

Comment: Thank you, as soon as I read that i noticed I forgot to put `.email` after current user....